# ValueConversion only when not selected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TextBox` which displays a file path to the user. The user can either use a OpenFileDialog to pick the file, which updates the text, or directly write/paste the path into the text box.

However, the text box is constrained in size and to avoid the path being cut off I'm using an custom `IValueConverter` to cut off part of the path to make sure both the drive letter, and the file name is visible.

For example, 
`C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\CompanyName\ExportType\ExportName\Exportfile1.bin`
becomes
`C:\...\ExportType\ExportName\Exportfile1.bin`

The problem occurs then when the user selects the field. As expected, the `ConvertBack` method of the IValueConverter is triggered, with the value now being the shortened path.

Is it then possible, without creating some custom intricate custom control, to show one formatted value when it's not selected, and the raw value when selected?

(I have access to the Telerik UI components, if it's already such a component there)

Comment: Perhaps trigger raising on event PreviousMouseDown to change property Text using concurrently mentioned converter and trigger on event PreviousMouseUp in order to bring back to previous value. Keep in mind that for textbox events MouseDown/Up are not raised.

Comment: PreviewMouseDown (I'm guessing you had a typo there?) is not a solution. The user can tab into it.

Comment: Set Focusable to false in order to deactivate. But I am getting more confused what you want to achieve.

Comment: That's not what I want to achieve. What do I need to clarify?

Comment: If it is not selected you need to have short version but when selection appears the long version has to be shown up, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But I'd rather not use code behind to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with solution without code behind

```
        <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Text">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Binding Path="nazwa" Converter="{StaticResource converter}" ConverterParameter="false"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold"/>
                        <Setter Property="Text">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Binding Path="nazwa" Converter="{StaticResource converter}" ConverterParameter="true"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Converter

```
 public class conv : IValueConverter
{
    private string track = null;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            track = value.ToString();
       return parameter.ToString().Equals("true") ? track: track.Substring(0,2);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Result when textbox is not selected
[image]

and when I select
[image]
just changing color yet, bytheway. The trick was to change parameters sending to converter. Let me know whether it works.

Comment: Ah, so you don't use a static binding, clever. I improved this by just not including the converter in the IsFocused trigger. Works great!